# Simple cache in ASP.net to implement NONCE store

Tags: c#, asp.net

What is the simplest and best way to implement the requirements around a NONCE (like in digest auth) within the ASP.net pipeline?

My initial thoughts are to use a singleton with a simple dictionary based object which keeps a list of used NONCE and has a timer which removes entries every X seconds.

Does anyone have a better solution - but one which doesn't involve using a Database or extra software install, such as Memcached?

Answer (score 0):

Almost anything will do here. Simple [application-level](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178594.aspx) `HashSet<string>` will suffice, even without periodic cleanups.

Remember, though, that ASP.NET applications (or, to be more precise, Application Pools inside IIS) get recycled, which means losing all non-persistent data.

Comment: Understand the recycling issue - that would result in a 401 in my case so the client could retry. This method was my initial plan but I am looking for some other ways if anyone has any. Thanks though, and I will mark as the answer if nothing better comes up.